# How to loop .subscribe observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently trying to make a function where it loops and by using .subscribe I'm getting an array object each time so that later on I can push the data inside an another array. The loop works but the problem is that the results is not what I want because the .subscribe part is printing the first array and then for the rest it's giving me null arrays whereas it suppose to print 20x the same array. I currently started experimenting with angular and to my knowledge of other languages I don't think that it's working good by first printing "Test"x20 and after goes inside the subscribe and printing.

**Function:**

```
testingFunction()
{
   let i: number = 0;

   while(i < 20){

   console.log("Test");

   this.testService.getAll().subscribe((object: any[]) => {
      console.log(object);
   })

    i++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Angular, you can make use of RxJS operators to handle this scenario. The [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) operator will allow you to wait for the while loop operation to be completed before returning all the observables.

This is how you can make use of the operator:

```
testingFunction() {
   let i: number = 0;
   const observablesList = []; 

   while(i < 20){
     observablesList.push(this.testService.getAll());
     i++;
   }
   forkJoin(observablesList).subscribe((response) => {
     console.log(response);
   });
}
```

Comment: Although this answer worked in grouping the arrays, I'm still having the first array visible and the others as null

Comment: @MexicoBoy in that case, what does `getAll()` do? I am guessing it is some other part in your codebase that is giving you an issue