# Angular RxJs how loop through array and assign http get requests to a single reactive observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need some assistance trying to loop through array of string numbers and assign http get requests to each string number and then assign the results to a single reactive observable. I was able to pull this off at the component level but I need the result in a observable that comes from my service. I am trying to leverage RxJs but having issues figuring out the correct syntax here. Hopefully this makes sense, thanks.

**myservice**

```
constructor(http: HttpClient)

 issueNumberString: string[];
 issuesObservable$;
 newIssueObservable$;
 private URL = '/my/api/stuff/';


getInfo() {
 for (let index = 0; index < this.issueNumbersString.length; index++) {
this.https.get<any[]>(this.URL + this.issueNumbersString[index])
.subscribe((response: any) => {
 return this.issuesObservable$.push(...response.records)  
})
}

this.newObservable$ = this.getInfo();
}
```

**.ts**

```
newObservable$ = this.myservice.newObservable$;

constructor(private service: myservice)
```

**html**

```
<div *ngIf="newObservable$ | async as entry">
    <div *ngFor="let n of entry">
```

Comment: Hey, you should be using forkJoin for this instance. I have a couple of examples here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/55686179/10959940) and there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59908693/10959940)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

goal is alittle unclear, but you should use `forkJoin` to run an array of observables:

```
getInfo() {
  return forkJoin(
    this.issueNumbersString.map(i => 
      this.http.get<any[]>(this.URL + i))
  ).pipe(
    map(recordsArrays => recordsArrays.reduce((arr, r) => arr.concat(r.records), [])
  )
}
```

the `forkJoin` gives you an array of your responses, then the `map` operator at the end to reduces it to one array of all records.